# Why my code using `exec()` is throwing an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making something that asks what you want to do and then does it. But when I call another file it doesn't read the entire file.

This is the code that's calling the other script

```
if math == "yes":
    exec(open("calculator.py").read());'''
```

This is the script that was called

```
'''
     else:
        print('You have not typed a valid 
operator, please run the program again.')
# Add again() function to calculate() function
    again()

def again():
    calc_again = input('''
Do you want to calculate again?
Please type Y for YES or N for NO.
''')

    if calc_again.upper() == 'Y':
        calculate()
    elif calc_again.upper() == 'N':
        print('See you later.')
    else:
        again()

calculate()
```

This is the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cahen\Desktop\chat bot.py", line 
17, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\cahen\Desktop\chat bot.py", line 
14, in main
    exec(open("calculator.py").read());
  File "<string>", line 47, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 32, in calculate
NameError: name 'again' is not defined
```

If i run calculator.py on its own it works fine.Its just when i call it from another script that is messes up.

Comment: Taking a step back from the immediate error, *why* are you running `calculator.py` like that? Why not *import* the functions from it, and *call* them?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite clear, you try to call the `again` function before defining it:

```
 '''
     else:
        print('You have not typed a valid 
operator, please run the program again.')
# Add again() function to calculate() function
    again()   # <----------------- CALLED HERE

def again():  # <----------------- DEFINED HERE
    calc_again = input('''
Do you want to calculate again?
Please type Y for YES or N for NO.
''')

    if calc_again.upper() == 'Y':
        calculate()
    elif calc_again.upper() == 'N':
        print('See you later.')
    else:
        again()

calculate()
```

Comment: I know that I call the again() function before its defined. The program works fine on its own its only when i call it that it runs into the problem of it not being defined.

Comment: @Chris I have no idea what you mean. I also have no idea what you're trying to accomplish here.